# Downloading files in an SDK add-on

Tags: javascript, pdf, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

There are so much topics about download files with addon sdk, but I try to deal with the problem from since few days and still I got nothing...

Ok, I work on AddOn Builder online on FireFox and I want get something like this:
Link with pdf -> I click on this by right mouse button -> chosing the "Get PDF" -> pdf is downloading to f.e. "c:\temp\"

I founded many of example codes, but every code doesn't work.
I don't have any errors, everything built ok, but when I clicked the "Get PDF" nothing saved in "c:\temp\" folder.
Every code is similar so i paste two of them:
This is my `exports.main = function()`

```
const { Cc, Ci, Cu } = require('chrome');
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
    label: "Get PDF",
    context: contextMenu.SelectorContext(" a[href *= '.pdf']"),
    contentScript: 'self.on("click", function (node, data) {' +
                    '  self.postMessage("test.pdf", "link to pdf");' +
                    '});',

    onMessage: function (sLocalFileName, sRemoteFileName)
        {
            var saveToDirectory = 'C:\\temp\\';

            //var chrome = require("chrome");

            var oIOService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService)

            var oLocalFile = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);
            oLocalFile.initWithPath(saveToDirectory + sLocalFileName);

            var oDownloadObserver = {onDownloadComplete: function(nsIDownloader, nsresult, oFile) {console.log('download complete...')}};

            var oDownloader = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/downloader;1"].createInstance();
            oDownloader.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDownloader);
            oDownloader.init(oDownloadObserver, oLocalFile);

            var oHttpChannel = oIOService.newChannel(sRemoteFileName, "", null);
            oHttpChannel.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
            oHttpChannel.asyncOpen(oDownloader, oLocalFile);    

        }
});
```

Second:

```
const { Cc, Ci, Cu } = require('chrome');
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
    label: "Get PDF",
    context: contextMenu.SelectorContext(" a[href *= '.pdf']"),
    contentScript: 'self.on("click", function (node, data) {' +
                    '  self.postMessage(node.href);' +
                    '});',

    onMessage: function (links)
        {

                // download from: aURLToDownload
                var downloadURI = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService).newURI(links, null, null);

                // download destination
                var outputFile = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile); 
                outputFile.initWithPath("c:\\temp\\1.pdf");

                var persist = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIWebBrowserPersist);


                persist.saveURI(downloadURI, null, null, null, "", outputFile);
        }
});
```

Please help!

Comment: What exactly does not work, as in, where does it break, with what errors? Also, you have `chrome.Cc`, but `const { Cc, Ci, Cu } = require('chrome');` so it should be just `Cc`.

Comment: I don't have any errors, everything built ok, but when I clicked the "Get PDF" nothing saved in "c:\\temp\\" folder and I don't now why.
Ok, I deleted "chrome", i edit code for a moment, but still nothing saved in temp folder.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I had a similar issue when I was playing around with this.. My code is very close to what you have but I added a few helpful steps.. First I get the directory path from preferences. Then I actually create the directory if it does not exist.. In my case I was creating sub-directories as well, you may not need it but just in case.

```
function DownloadFile(sdirectory, sLocalFileName, sRemoteFileName)
{
var baseDirectory = require('sdk/simple-prefs').prefs['downloadpath'] + "\\";
var saveToDirectory = baseDirectory + sdirectory + '\\';

var oLocalDir = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(chrome.Ci.nsILocalFile);
oLocalDir.initWithPath(saveToDirectory);
if(!oLocalDir.exists())
{
    oLocalDir.create(1,777);
}

var oIOService = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(chrome.Ci.nsIIOService)

var oLocalFile = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(chrome.Ci.nsILocalFile);
oLocalFile.initWithPath(saveToDirectory + sLocalFileName);

var oDownloadObserver = {onDownloadComplete: function(nsIDownloader, nsresult, oFile) 
{
    console.log('download complete...');

}};

var oDownloader = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/network/downloader;1"].createInstance();
oDownloader.QueryInterface(chrome.Ci.nsIDownloader);
oDownloader.init(oDownloadObserver, oLocalFile);

var oHttpChannel = oIOService.newChannel(sRemoteFileName, "", null);
oHttpChannel.QueryInterface(chrome.Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
oHttpChannel.asyncOpen(oDownloader, oLocalFile);
```

}

First thing you should do if you have not already, go to about:config and change devtools.errorconsole.enabled to true.

Next add a log statement to the beginning of your download event.. I would actually suggest you break out that method and just call the DownloadFile method in you event.

The most important thing I found out I had to do was sanitize my file name.. with

```
var file = "somefilename"
file = file.replace(/[/\\:?<>|\"]+/g, "");
```

If the file name with illegal characters, or a directory path wrong at all I had the same issues.

So I would make your code like..

```
....
onMessage: function (filename, fileURL)
{
  console.log("Message Event, filename: " + filename +" URL: " +fileURL);
   DownloadFile(filename,fileURL);
}});

function DownloadFile(sLocalFileName, sRemoteFileName)
{
var baseDirectory = require('sdk/simple-prefs').prefs['downloadpath'] + "\\";
var saveToDirectory = baseDirectory;

var oLocalDir = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(chrome.Ci.nsILocalFile);
oLocalDir.initWithPath(saveToDirectory);
if(!oLocalDir.exists())
{
    oLocalDir.create(1,777);
}

var oIOService = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(chrome.Ci.nsIIOService)

var oLocalFile = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(chrome.Ci.nsILocalFile);
oLocalFile.initWithPath(saveToDirectory + sLocalFileName);

var oDownloadObserver = {onDownloadComplete: function(nsIDownloader, nsresult, oFile) {console.log('download complete...')}};

var oDownloader = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/network/downloader;1"].createInstance();
oDownloader.QueryInterface(chrome.Ci.nsIDownloader);
oDownloader.init(oDownloadObserver, oLocalFile);

var oHttpChannel = oIOService.newChannel(sRemoteFileName, "", null);
oHttpChannel.QueryInterface(chrome.Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
oHttpChannel.asyncOpen(oDownloader, oLocalFile);   
}
```

**EDIT :** 
Forgot to mention you need this in your package.json file, to be able to set and retrieve the preferences.

```
"preferences": [{
    "name": "downloadpath",
    "title": "Download Path",
    "description": "Select a directory to download",
    "type": "directory"
}]
```